# Who has given / who gave / who hit/ who has hit?

Tags: present-perfect

What does the difference between the two come down to?

> Who gave it to you? - Who has given it to you?
>
> Who hit you? - Who has hit you?

Usually, the past simple overrides, but I think there must be contexts in which the present perfect is used.

Comment: Don't understand this question, particularly since you have four sentences and ask something about a difference between two.

Comment: Oh, really? Have you ever heard anything about the present perfect and the past simple?

Comment: The present perfect implies that the action was recent.

Comment: Kate, americans can use the past simple with an action which took place a second ago.